# how can I use bootstrap grid style in angular without disturbing/overriding angular material design

Tags: angular, angular-material, npm-install, ng-bootstrap

If I use ng-bootstrap, `grid style` does not work but when I use bootstrap (providing it in style.css or in angular.json style[] array) grid style it works fine, but it overrides the angular material designs.

`ng-bootstrap and bootstrap both I installed from npm`

I used `<div class="col-md-6 md-offset-3"></div>`

Comment: Bootstrap was not designed to be used in combination with Angular Material. Since both libraries provide similar types of features, results might not be predictable as you are discovering. Use one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even our minimal inclusion of Bootstrap adds couple of styles that don’t play so nicely with the Angular Material out of the box. Let’s create new `styles-reset.scss` file with the following content and import it after the original Bootstrap imports in the main `styles.scss` file.

```
* { &:active, :focus { outline: none !important; }} Label { margin-bottom: 0;}
```

Bootstrap also sets `link color` and uses `underline text-decoration` on the `hovered links`. We can remove this styles by adjusting content of the `styles-variables.scss` file like this and import it in the `style.scss`

`$link-hover-decoration: none;`    // remove underline from button links

`$link-color: #3f51b5;`            // set link color based on the used material theme

`$link-hover-color: currentColor;`

Reference from : https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/how-to-build-responsive-layouts-with-bootstrap-4-and-angular-6-cfbb108d797b

Answer (score 15):

If you just need to use the bootstrap grid, you can add in your `package.json` dependencies: `"bootstrap": "4.3.1"` and `npm i`
then in your `styles.scss` add `@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css';` **upside** the angular material theme import and there you go, you imported only the grid style without all other stuffs and material theme is still the same.
[Here is an example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shrkrc)
[Here is the source of the unminified file you imported](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css)

Comment: I tried importing ```@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css';``` it was working fine but it overrides the ```material design ```. By the way thanks for your answer.

Comment: What exactly was overriden from material design. I'm asking because I did this way and until now and material design seems to be ok.
The only difference is that I imported `bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss`.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

you can localise bootstrap inside components using this in your `styles.scss`

```
.bootstrapped {
  @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css';
}

<div class="bootstrapped"><div class="container">etc</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a branch of material design for bootstrap specifically aimed at Angular that should solve this problem for you.

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/

I use this in my own apps and the grid system works perfectly.

If you want to install via npm: https://github.com/mdbootstrap/bootstrap-material-design

Tutorial showing use of mdbootstrap: https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/corporate-website-lesson-1/

Hope this helps!